# spring EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder - Where is the Derby Database

Tags: java, spring, derby, embedded-database

I am using the following code to create Derby Embeded Database.

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource", destroyMethod = "shutdown")
@Profile("test")
public DataSource dataSourceForTest() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .generateUniqueName(true)
            .setName("myDBDerby")
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.Derby)
            .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
            .ignoreFailedDrops(true)
            .addScript("schema.sql")
            .addScripts("data.sql")
            .build();
}
```

I can run query on the database. However, I could not find the myDBDerby directory which is the database.

Can anyone please let me know where the database might be located and how can I set a specific location for the database.

Comment: Embedded as in In-Memory...

Comment: @M.Deinum How to put this database in a directory?

Comment: By not using the `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder` but configuire a regular datasource.